# How to diff between 2 html codes with Python?

Tags: python, html, diff

I'm wondering what is the best way to do a Diff on two HTML codes?
I prefer to get the output as Python object and not as a HTML report or something like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use difflib library available as a part of python standard library. Refer it at https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

Comment: I looked on it.. but the results there is per char, i look for something that diffs by a line